# Handlebars always using default template

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm sending an email with:

```
            var data = {
                to: "toemail",
                from: "fromemail",
                template: 'sendtimesheetemail',
                subject: 'TimeSheet',
                context: {
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
                    user: user.email
                }
            };

            smtpTransport.sendMail(data, function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    return res.json({ message: 'Email has been sent' });
                } else {
                    return res.status(423).json({ error: err });//done(err);
                }
            })
```

Set up with

```
var handlebarsOptions = {
    viewEngine: {
        extname: '.html',
        layoutsDir: 'templates',
        defaultLayout : 'forgotpasswordemail',
        partialsDir : 'templates'
    },
    viewPath: 'templates/',
    extName: '.html'
};

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "hotmail",
    auth: {
        user: email,
        pass: pass
    }
});
```

and the url and user are replaced as expected as well as the email subject, and I replace the template with a file that does not exist Postman indicates we are looking in the right directory.

However, the template which is actually used is always the default forgotpasswordemail?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, just set the defaultLayout to an empty string and it'll depend on the template in the mailoptions:

```
var handlebarsOptions = {
    viewEngine: {
        extname: '.html',
        layoutsDir: 'templates',
        defaultLayout : '',
        partialsDir : 'templates'
    },
    viewPath: 'templates/',
    extName: '.html'
};
```